# XSLT 2 character only generate-id

Tags: xslt

I'd like to use `generate-id` in my xslt stylesheet.
However, this function generates a 8 character long id.

Is there a way to make the id have only two characters ? Of course this makes a limited number of possible id (1296 possibilities), but I will never need to go beyond that limit.

Thanks

Comment: It might always be an 8-character string for your XSLT processor, but that's a feature of your processor, not of the language specification.

Answer (score 3):

If you only need the ID to be unique for nodes within a single document, you could use

```
<xsl:number count="*" level="any" from="/*" format="a"/>
```

Comment: This is the solution i've come to. Unfortunately, I cannot use it as I would do `generate-id(..)`

Answer (score 0):

You'd have much more than 1296 possibilities with 2 characters if you wanted to use all the unicode characters that are allowed in an XML name!

Unfortunately, XSLT processors are free to decide how that create IDs for the `generate-id()` function (meaning that depending on the processor you are using you can get more or less then 8 characters).

That being said, if that's really important to you, you should be able to write your own `generate-id()` based on the number of preceding siblings and ancestor node nodes (`count(ancestor::node()|preceding::node())`)... You could convert this number into a two character id using lookup tables or any other mechanism and that would probably not be very efficient but that should work...